# How to iterate over rows effectively in pandas data-frame using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have a data-frame which looks like:

```
A         B       C
13.06   12.95   -0.11
92.56   104.63  12.07
116.49  219.27  102.78
272.11  487.26  215.15
300.11  780.75  480.64
```

There are like 1 million records.

I want to create a column D which is calcualted as below:

First value of column `D` will be 0 and then:

`Col D3`= `=(D2+1)*C3/B3`

`Col D4`= `=(D3+1)*C4/B4`

Column D present value depends on previous value.

Here is the result:

```
D
0
0.115358884
0.52281017
0.672397915
1.02955022
```

I can solve it using `for loop and loc` but its taking lot of time. Can I solve it in more effective pythonic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive calculations are not vectorisable, for improve performance is used  [**numba**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#using-numba):

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def f(a, b, c):
    d = np.empty(a.shape)
    d[0] = 0
    for i in range(1, a.shape[0]):
        d[i] = (d[i-1] + 1) * c[i] / b[i]
    return d

df['D'] = f(df['A'].to_numpy(), df['B'].to_numpy(), df['C'].to_numpy())
print (df)
        A       B       C         D
0   13.06   12.95   -0.11  0.000000
1   92.56  104.63   12.07  0.115359
2  116.49  219.27  102.78  0.522810
3  272.11  487.26  215.15  0.672398
4  300.11  780.75  480.64  1.029550
```

Comment: Giving error : TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
non-precise type array(pyobject, 1d, C)
[1] During: typing of argument at <ipython-input-6-0d768ce11abe> (3)

File "<ipython-input-6-0d768ce11abe>", line 3:
def calc(a,b,c):
    d = np.empty(a.shape)
    ^

Comment: @MAC - Are columns filled by numeric?

Comment: df = {'HW':['13.06', '92.56', '116.49', '272.11','300.11'], 'IBC':[12.95, 104.63, 219.27, 487.26,780.75],'jik':[-0.11, 12.07, 102.78, 215.15,480.64]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

Comment: @MAC - exactly, problem is `HW` is filled by strings, not numeric. Need convert it to numbers, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas)