# Dataframe looping in a specific way

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a some dataframe object:

```
df.head()

A   B   C
0   7   7     
1   3   6     
2   5   5  
3   2   7     
4   4   3
```

I would like to compare for example **A** and **B** at **n** while also using **C** at **n-1** to create a new row, so let's say D = A<sub>n</sub> * B<sub>n</sub> + C<sub>n-1</sub>.

At first I used a generic python loop, but I quickly realized this was very slow with large datasets. Then I started looking at numpy vectorization (which is **very** fast) but I couldn't figure out a way to get previous entries.

What other alternatives do I have while keeping it nice and fast?

Comment: First I think need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62261221/2901002), if not `shift` is better here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution using [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas-series-shift)

```
df['D'] = df.A * df.B + df.C.shift(1, fill_value = 0)
```

---

```
   A  B  C   D
0  0  7  7   0
1  1  3  6  10
2  2  5  5  16
3  3  2  7  11
4  4  4  3  23
```

Comment: Thank you.
fillna(0.0) is redundant as shift() has a fill_value parameter, so shift(periods=1, fill_value=0.0).